# simple regex search+replacement

Tags: regex

All of the tutorials related to regular expressions I have found very difficult to understand, so thank you in advanced for helping me here on this stupidly simple question.

I'm trying to change a string of the form 0n to the form n
so "02" => "2" and "06" => "6"

I know the search regex must be 0[0-9], but I don't know what the replacement regex must be.

Comment: What programming language are you working with? Rather than regex, you likely have available a proper method to parse a base 10 integer from a zero-padded value.

Comment: well I'm doing it in the find+replace of notepad++

Comment: I see - I'm not familiar with the grammar Notepad++ uses for replacements (whether `$1` or `\1`, etc) but `0(\d)` replaced with `$1`

Comment: that worked Michael
the replace is \1
^^ ty

Answer (score 1):

Search Regex:

```
*(0)[0-9]+*
```

Replace $1, which would be group 1, a.k.a the `0` with ""

Comment: I'm not sure that Notepad++ only replaces catch groups. Try [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `0(?=[0-9]+)`.